# What is a Python websocket server supposed to do when an invalid path is requested?

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to write a Python websockets server. In all the examples I can find on Google, the callback function takes a path .. and then completely ignores it.

What am I supposed to do if I want to reject a request because it's asking for an invalid path? Am I supposed to raise an exception? Return a special object? Call some method? I can't understand why the documentation seemingly has no mention of this situation; am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide some samples of callback functions that ignore the requested path?

Comment: Cmd-F path: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/tutorial2.html

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/94580/websockets.serve

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/how-to-implement-a-websocket-in-python/

Comment: https://www.piesocket.com/blog/python-websocket/